# Make Rails use schema.rb instead of reading the schema from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, sidekiq

Why ActiveRecord queries the database to know the database schema? Can't it simply read the `db/schema.rb`?

I have some Sidekiq workers that for performance cannot connect to the database. The job itself doesn't use the database at all (or at least I expected so):

```
n = Notification.new
n.body = cache["body"] # cache is from Redis
...
```

But the first line actually calls the database!

Is there anything I can do to make Rails read the `schema.rb`, or, in any case, instantiate a `Notification` without the  database?

I don't want to create a separate model that doesn't inherits from ActiveRecord. I need the same model: sometimes it's loaded from the database and sometimes from Redis.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate object which represents the Redis version of the object and use an included module to share methods between the AR and Redis versions.  ActiveRecord::Base instances are not designed to be used without the database.